# npm install with major and minor version dependecies

Tags: npm, package, dependencies, version, package.json

I am trying to create an **npm** package. Trying to install `Lodash` with major and minor version dependencies. It should be like minor version 17 and major version 4.

How is it possible?
I have tried
`npm install lodash@^4 && ~17` but it seems not what I am expecting. It should me clearly mentioned in package.json as major and minor version dependencies right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install lodash@4.17` will install `lodash@4.17.x` and update `package.json` appropriately to require 4.17.x. The entry in `package.json` could have the format `"lodash": "4.17"` or something more like `"lodash": "^4.17.21"`, depending on what version of `npm` you are running.

Comment: thanks @Trott. it should only install a specific version right? but what I want here is to install the package with major and minor version dependencies. could you give something on that.

Comment: No, what I wrote above does what you are asking for. `npm install lodash@4.17` will install 4.17.x where x is the highest number/most recent version it can find in the registry. In addition, it will write to your `package.json` in such a way as to do that same behavior for everyone who installs your package.